# What sensors to measure grass growth?

Tags: sensors

I would like to make a small project, which would allow me to recognize if the grass has grow enough to lawn. I don't know too much the ecosystem of available sensors for such problem. And I have a lot of grass and some irregular areas to clean once in a while.

Is that something I can do with an arduino and some sensors, or should I need to use more processing power and cameras/AI?

TIA!

Comment: measure the grass indirectly ... keep track of the weather and of the irrigation schedule

Comment: @jsotola that seems a quite complex model to implement, depending on a lot of variables, which in final terms is more expensive than using some cheap sensors.

Answer (score 2):

My idea: Two light sensors on a short stick embedded in the ground. If the top sensor detects light, but the bottom one does not it means that it's daytime, and grass is long enough that it covered the bottom sensor. You will probably need several of those, because there is no guarantee that grass will actually cover the bottom sensor, and you will need to filter out random elements by testing if values don't change to much.

Comment: That's an idea. In fact we could just need one that's not covered by the grass, to contrast the light of all others that could be at ground level...

Comment: I think having them in close proximity pairs would be better for detecting things like building shadow at the end of the day or a dog laying on the grass for an hour.

Comment: might not work in the real world because the lens will be dirty in a month or so.

Comment: Be sure not to mow only the gras not the sensors :D